# I want to change chart value according to numbers of record in database

Tags: laravel-5, canvasjs

**Problem** I have bar chart currently I assign value and I want to increase the values of barchart with my database table(id) when the a record is enterd the value of id increase then chart value increase. How to access the value of id from database and pass that value in view. any help?

```
    **Blade code**

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

  title:{
    text: "Sales Analytics"              
  },
  data: [//array of dataSeries              
    { //dataSeries object

     /*** Change type "column" to "bar", "area", "line" or "pie"***/
     type: "column",
     dataPoints: [
     { label: "orders", y: 40 },
     { label: "Bookings", y: 18 },
     { label: "Messages", y: 45 },                                    
     { label: "Products", y: 50 }

     ]
   }
   ]
   });

  chart.render();
                                                   }
</script>

  **AbcController.php**

    public function showAdmin(orders $orders){
     $data = orders::lists(['id']);
    return view('admin.orders')->with('orders', $data);
                                              }

         **Model Code**

      <?php

       namespace App;

      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

      class orders extends Model
     {
      protected $table = 'orders';
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, can you just clarify this a little more. So your are passing in an `orders` variable set to `$data` and you want to use it inside your chart here; `{ label: "orders", y: 40 },`. So that `y` is equal to the value?

Comment: @James Thanks for reply . yes Y is value.I just want to replace the value of Y to  the value of  id coloumn in orders table in my mysql.I just want to know how to I access max value of id from orders table and pass this value at my blade page